# Webview Uri Redirect by scanning barcodes with React Native, Expo

Tags: react-native

I am creating a barcode scanner using React Native and Expo.

I am trying to pass a new URL to a WebView after scanning a barcode.

But I am not sure how.

Please help.

---

```
export default function App() {
  const [hasPermission, setHasPermission] = useState(null);
  const [scanned, setScanned] = useState(false);
  const [modalVisible, setModalVisible] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const { status } = await BarCodeScanner.requestPermissionsAsync();
      setHasPermission(status === 'granted');
    })();
  }, []);

  const handleBarCodeScanned = ({ type, data }) => {
    setScanned(true);
    setModalVisible(true);
  };

  if (hasPermission === null) {
    return <Text>Requesting for camera permission</Text>;
  }
  if (hasPermission === false) {
    return <Text>No access to camera</Text>;
  }

  return (
    <View
      style={{
        flex: 1,
        flexDirection: 'column'
      }}>
      <Modal
        animationType="slide"
        transparent={false}
        visible={modalVisible}
        onRequestClose={() => {
          setScanned(false);
        }}>
        <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
          <WebView
            style={{ flex: 1 }}
            source={{ uri: 'http://domain.biz/' }}
          />

          <TouchableHighlight
            style={{
              backgroundColor:'black',
              padding: 15,
              alignItems: 'center'
            }}
            onPress={() => {
              setModalVisible(!modalVisible);
              setScanned(false);
            }}
            underlayColor='slategray'
          >
            <Text style={{ color:'white', fontSize: 15 }}>Re Scan</Text>
          </TouchableHighlight>
        </View>
      </Modal>

      <BarCodeScanner
        onBarCodeScanned={scanned ? undefined : handleBarCodeScanned}
        style={{
          flex: 1,
          justifyContent: 'center',
          alignItems: 'center',
        }}>
        <View style={{ marginBottom: 100 }}>
          <View style={{ alignItems: 'center', marginBottom: 5 }}>
            <Image
              style={{
                width: 100,
                height: 100,
                resizeMode: 'contain',
                marginBottom: 20,
              }}
              source={{ uri: 'http://domain.biz/img/logo_dark.png' }}
            />
            <Text style={{ color: 'white', fontSize: 20, fontWeight: 'bold', paddingBottom: 10}}>
              QR Code Reader v0.5
            </Text>
          </View>
          <View
            style={{
              borderColor: 'white',
              borderTopWidth: 5,
              borderBottomWidth: 5,
              borderLeftWidth: 1,
              borderRightWidth: 1,
              paddingVertical: 80,
              paddingHorizontal: 100,
            }}
          />

          <View style={{ alignItems: 'center', marginTop: 5 }}>
            <Text style={{ color: 'white', fontSize: 15}}>
              QR Scan...
            </Text>
          </View>
        </View>
      </BarCodeScanner>
    </View>
  );
}
```

I am creating a barcode scanner using React Native and Expo.

I am trying to pass a new URL to a WebView after scanning a barcode.

But I am not sure how.

Please help.

Comment: Could you add your whole source with imports and relevant parts from the package.json? This way I can compile a solution and test it. Otherwise I can only send some untested code you have to debug yourself ;)

Comment: Nevermind. I found you used the expo examples and managed to set up the code myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the work. I save the url from the scanner in state.uri and use that instead of a static string. 
For testing purposes I used this barcode which leads to this answer:

[image: link to Stackoverflow]

Best, Paul

```
  import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
  import { Text, View, StyleSheet, Button, Modal, TouchableHighlight, Image } from 'react-native';
  import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview';
  import { BarCodeScanner } from 'expo-barcode-scanner';

  export default function App(){
    const [hasPermission, setHasPermission] = useState(null);
    const [scanned, setScanned] = useState(true);
    const [modalVisible, setModalVisible] = useState(true);
    const [uri, setUri] = useState('https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61977154/webview-uri-redirect-by-scanning-barcodes-with-react-native-expo');


useEffect(() => {
  (async () => {
    const { status } = await BarCodeScanner.requestPermissionsAsync();
    setHasPermission(status === 'granted');
  })();
}, []);

const handleBarCodeScanned = ({ type, data }) => {
  setScanned(true);
  setModalVisible(true);
    // console.warn("Scan returned " + data);
    setUri({ uri: data })
};

if (hasPermission === null) {
  return <Text>Requesting for camera permission</Text>;
}
if (hasPermission === false) {
  return <Text>No access to camera</Text>;
}

return (
  <View
    style={{
      flex: 1,
      flexDirection: 'column'
    }}>
    <Modal
      animationType="slide"
      transparent={false}
      visible={modalVisible}
      onRequestClose={() => {
        setScanned(false);
      }}>
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <WebView
          style={{ flex: 1 }}
          source={{uri: uri['uri']}}
        />

        <TouchableHighlight
          style={{
            backgroundColor:'black',
            padding: 15,
            alignItems: 'center'
          }}
          onPress={() => {
            setModalVisible(!modalVisible);
            setScanned(false);
          }}
          underlayColor='slategray'
        >
          <Text style={{ color:'white', fontSize: 15 }}>Re Scan</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>
      </View>
    </Modal>

    <BarCodeScanner
      onBarCodeScanned={scanned ? undefined : handleBarCodeScanned}
      style={{
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
      }}>
      <View style={{ marginBottom: 100 }}>
        <View style={{ alignItems: 'center', marginBottom: 5 }}>
          <Image
            style={{
              width: 100,
              height: 100,
              resizeMode: 'contain',
              marginBottom: 20,
            }}
            source={{ uri: 'http://domain.biz/img/logo_dark.png' }}
          />
          <Text style={{ color: 'white', fontSize: 20, fontWeight: 'bold', paddingBottom: 10}}>
            QR Code Reader v0.5
          </Text>
        </View>
        <View
          style={{
            borderColor: 'white',
            borderTopWidth: 5,
            borderBottomWidth: 5,
            borderLeftWidth: 1,
            borderRightWidth: 1,
            paddingVertical: 80,
            paddingHorizontal: 100,
          }}
        />

        <View style={{ alignItems: 'center', marginTop: 5 }}>
          <Text style={{ color: 'white', fontSize: 15}}>
            QR Scan...
          </Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    </BarCodeScanner>
  </View>
);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Here it is, but I have passed the data from the other page `name:index.js`.
You can use the linking component to open every URL passed through `{data}`

---

```
import React from "react";
import { View, Text, Linking, TouchableOpacity } from "react-native";

const detail = ({ route, navigation }) => {

  const data = route.params;

  const [uri, setUri] = React.useState({});
  return (
    <View>
      

      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => Linking.openURL(data)}>
        <Text>{data}</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
};

export default detail;
```